# Разрешение браузеру открывать файлы .txt CGI

Tags: python, cgi

У меня есть скрипт на Python CGI. К примеру, `XXX.XXX.X:80` - адрес. У меня есть файл `1.txt`.
Если я напишу `XXX.XXX.X:80/1.txt`, то увижу значения файла. Как запретить переход через ссылку?

Comment: Настроить соответствующие настройки доступа в настройках вашего веб-сервера.

Comment: Если вам нужно использовать данные из `1.txt` в каких-то других местах вашего сервера, то лучше тогда использовать функцию `cgi.parse()` и забирать так данные из файла, скрытого от чужих глаз